# How to roof mount a small TV antenna?

Tags: wiring, tv-antenna

More specifically how to run cables from my Clearstream 2 antenna to the junction box and deal with grounding.  I plan on installing the mast and antenna on the south side of my roof so that it is facing the broadcast towers.  I'll need to run the coax to the north side where the junction box is.  Here are my questions:

1. The north side of the house has a gutter.  Can I run the cable over the gutter leave a drip loop and connect it to the soffit and then down the wall to the junction box/splitter?
2. I know I need a grounding block to ground the coaxial connection but do I need to ground the mast?  And if I do, how do I do about that?  I've yet to see any [images of the mast for a clearstream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPOgqcSofQI) with a grounding wire coming off of them.

The grounding rods for the house are already on the north side of the house so I have that going for me.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Grounding the mast is a very good idea if it is metal. You can get ground clamps that are designed for use with water pipes and conduit of practically any diameter. They are two curved pieces of metal that have machine screws on either side to clamp to the pipe. There is also a screw terminal for your ground wire. I would put a separate ground rod in, but bond it with your other grounds at one place.

I would recommend not running the coax over the gutter, or for that matter over any exposed roofing material period, as the cable will be exposed to UV radiation and break down faster, as well as trapping leaves and other foreign matter. I would run the coax cable around under the eaves around the house.

One final thing to mention, is to use outdoor rated cable and connectors as corrosion can be a real issue. Also check your local codes and HOA's to see if they have any restrictions to tall masts mounted on your house.

Comment: I'm curious what the risk is if I don't ground the mast?  I notice just about every satellite dish uses a similar (slightly heftier) mast and I never see those grounded.

Comment: It is for lightning protection. A mast is basically a giant lightning rod on your house. If lightning strikes, you want the current to go somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I understand that lightning could strike but then why doesn't DirecTV/Dish ground their masts?  I would assume the risk is low or they would be grounding them to reduce their exposure to being sued.

Comment: I do not know. If anyone else knows, would be interested as well

Comment: Just as an FYI: I recently pulled down an aged DirecTV dish and the coaxial cable that ran to the dish had another solid core wire inside the casing next to the coax that could be separated and attached to the dish.  I assume the other side was only attached to the coax grounding block.